# How do I get 2 sets of columns of a df?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df with 12 features columns, one label column, then another eight feature columns.

I set X and Y thus:

```
y = df.iloc[:, 12] #Label variable
X = df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:12, 13:]] #Features
```

This selects y ok but x is the first 12 columns followed by the first 13 columns, whereas I want all the columns except the 13th. There has to be an easier way but I am a noob to this.

Comment: For that to work, you should properly specify the slices `np.r_[0:12, 13:df.shape[1]]`

Comment: Excellent! Want to put it as an answer? Maybe explain why mine was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column from original to new Series `y`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,15))).add_prefix('col')
print (df)
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9  col10  col11  \
0     8     8     3     7     7     0     4     2     5     2      2      2   
1     4     0     9     6     2     4     1     5     3     4      4      3   
2     7     7     0     2     9     9     3     2     5     8      1      0   
3     0     8     2     5     1     8     1     5     4     2      8      3   
4     3     6     3     4     7     6     3     9     0     4      4      5   

   col12  col13  col14  
0      1      0      8  
1      7      1      1  
2      7      6      2  
3      5      0      9  
4      7      6      6
```

---

```
y = df.pop(df.columns[12])
print (y)
0    1
1    7
2    7
3    5
4    7
Name: col12, dtype: int32

print (df)
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9  col10  col11  \
0     8     8     3     7     7     0     4     2     5     2      2      2   
1     4     0     9     6     2     4     1     5     3     4      4      3   
2     7     7     0     2     9     9     3     2     5     8      1      0   
3     0     8     2     5     1     8     1     5     4     2      8      3   
4     3     6     3     4     7     6     3     9     0     4      4      5   

   col13  col14  
0      0      8  
1      1      1  
2      6      2  
3      0      9  
4      6      6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this by index, use drop:

```
col = [13]
X = df.drop(df.columns[col],axis=1)
```